# getting 500 error by calling any route which is getting data from database in azure-web-app-service

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-apicontroller

recently i have deployed my .net 5.0 api in azure web app without azure database. The app is running fine but i am not able to call any route which is getting data from my postgresql database. The api and getting data from my database is working fine in my local pc, but when i call any route in azure web app i get 500 internal server error and the detail error look like this.

**error #1**

```
Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection
EventId: 20004
SpanId: 81307fd2722df04f
TraceId: 17283bbac7e9c74ab0dea8dafdf0a12a
ParentId: 0000000000000000
ConnectionId: 0HMB63E788EM6
RequestId: 0HMB63E788EM6:00000004
RequestPath: /api/someList
ActionId: d26cb19d-75cd-4847-828f-a74e2b5324ee
ActionName: QuranApi.Controllers.QuranTextController.GetSomeList (MyApi)

An error occurred using the connection to database 'MyDatabase' on server 
'tcp://localhost:5432'.
```

**error #2**

```
Category: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
EventId: 10100
SpanId: 81307fd2722df04f
TraceId: 17283bbac7e9c74ab0dea8dafdf0a12a
ParentId: 0000000000000000
ConnectionId: 0HMB63E788EM6
RequestId: 0HMB63E788EM6:00000004
RequestPath: /api/someList
ActionId: d26cb19d-75cd-4847-828f-a74e2b5324ee
ActionName: QuranApi.Controllers.QuranTextController.GetSomeList (MyApi)

An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 
'QuranApi.PostgreSqlContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to 
a transient failure.
 ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a 
socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout 
timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.
OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean 
errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean 
errorsExpected)
at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand. 
ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal. 
SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.
InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)at 
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.
NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, 
Func`3 verifySucceeded)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at 
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.
NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, 
Func`3 verifySucceeded)at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal. 
SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to 
a transient failure.
---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a 
socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, 
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout 
timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()at
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean 
errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean 
errorsExpected)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean 
errorsExpected) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.
ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.
SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.
Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at 
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.
Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.
Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

**error #3**

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
EventId: 13
SpanId: 81307fd2722df04f
TraceId: 17283bbac7e9c74ab0dea8dafdf0a12a
ParentId: 0000000000000000
ConnectionId: 0HMB63E788EM6
RequestId: 0HMB63E788EM6:00000004
RequestPath: /api/someList

Connection id "0HMB63E788EM6", Request id "0HMB63E788EM6:00000004": An unhandled 
exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to 
a transient failure.
---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a 
socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

**my Program.cs File**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {                  
                webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseUrls("https://localhost:5000", "https://IP-Address-of-my-PC")
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**And my Startup.cs File**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        var sqlConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionString"];
        services.AddDbContext<PostgreSqlContext>(options => 
        options.UseNpgsql(connectionString: sqlConnectionString));
        services.AddScoped<IDataAccessProvider, DataAccessProvider>();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "MyApi",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(options => 
        options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyApi v1"));
    }
}
```

i would be very happy if anybody can help me with this. I dont know what to do.

Comment: the following line only works locally. I believe this is one of the problems. The other one may be the connection string, please take a look if you proper define it                .UseUrls("https://localhost:5000", "https://IP-Address-of-my-PC")

Comment: how can I change that so that it works in azure and locally and my connStr looks like this "User ID=myUserId;Password=myPassword;Host=myHost;Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=myDatabase; Integrated Security=true; Pooling=true;" this works fine in my local pc.

Comment: yes, but azure cannot connect to the database running in your machine. You'll need to create a database on Azure, and point the connection string to that